# Spring MVC @RequestMapping params has multiple values with one param

Tags: spring-mvc

I verify entitlement with Spring Security, but there are different entitlement with one param which has multiple values.

I want match one param with multiple values in one method like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{domain}/aa", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"requestedAction=a||b"})
```

I have already try many way such as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{domain}/aa", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"requestedAction=a","requestedAction=b"})
```

but they don't work.
I don't want split this to two methods.
Is there any way to make this value without case sensitive, if there no way to supports multiple values.

Comment: Did you find a solution on the "OR" statement?

Comment: please use the annotation @PreAuthorize, it can support you customer your authorization, so you can use OR statement.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is finally solved.
I use @PreAuthorize replace @Secured

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?

Answer (score -1):

You can try in this way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{domain}/aa", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String someMethod(@RequestParam String param1, @RequestParam String param2) {
    // use the request parameters
}
```

Comment: No, i want use the annotation @secured to verify entitlement, so i should check the param when the request dispatch.